# How to read std::queue shared with another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

My code acquires images and processes them. Performance is critical for my code, so I've tried my hand at multi-threading. Currently, I've only made the acquiring part a separate thread. I'm implementing a simple FIFO buffer using `std::queue` that stores the acquired images. The acquisition function `AcquireImages` writes raw image data to this buffer indefinitely until user interruption. Processing function, `ProcessImages` reads the buffer and processes the image data (currently in the main thread but I'm planning to make this a separate thread as well once I've ironed out issues). Here's my code (modified to form an [MCV example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

#define NUM_CAMERAS 2

void AcquireImages(std::queue<unsigned char*> &rawImageQueue, std::atomic<bool> &quit)
{
    unsigned char* rawImage{};

    while (!quit)
    {
        for (int camera = 0; camera < NUM_CAMERAS; camera++)
        {
            switch (camera)
            {
            case 0:
                rawImage = (unsigned char*)"Cam0Image";
                break;
            case 1:
                rawImage = (unsigned char*)"Cam1Image";
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            
            rawImageQueue.push(std::move(rawImage));
        }
    }
}

int ProcessImages(const std::vector<unsigned char*> &rawImageVec, const int count)
{
    // Do something to the raw image vector

    if (count > 10)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    } // In my application, this function only returns non-zero upon user interception.
}


int main()
{
    // Preparation
    std::vector<unsigned char*> rawImageVec;
    rawImageVec.reserve(NUM_CAMERAS);
    std::queue<unsigned char*> rawImageQueue;
    int count{};

    const unsigned int nThreads = 1;    // this might grow later

    std::atomic<bool> loopFlags[nThreads];
    std::thread       threads[nThreads];

    // Start threads
    for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
        loopFlags[i] = false;
        threads[i] = std::thread(AcquireImages, rawImageQueue, ref(loopFlags[i]));
    }

    // Process images
    while (true)
    {
    
        // Process the images
        for (int cam{}; cam < NUM_CAMERAS; ++cam)
        {
            rawImageVec.push_back(rawImageQueue.front());
            rawImageQueue.pop();
        }

        int processResult = ProcessImages(move(rawImageVec), count);
        if (processResult)
        {
            std::cout << "Leaving while loop.\n"; // In my application this is triggered by the user
            break;
        }

        rawImageVec.clear();
        ++count;
    }

    // Shutdown other threads
    for (auto & flag : loopFlags) {
        flag = true;
    }

    // Wait for threads to actually finish.
    for (auto& thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Some of you may have already noticed my blunder. What I know is that this program throws an exception at`rawImageVec.push_back(rawImageQueue.front());`.

The output after throwing the exception reads as follows:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\deque
Line: 329

Expression: deque iterator not dereferencable
```

I understand the cause of the issue is probably that I'm reading something that is shared with another thread (Am I correct?). How do I resolve this?

I followed Praetorian's advice in the comments, after checking to see if `rawImageQueue` is empty, I see that it's always empty. I'm not sure what's causing this.

Comment: Protect the queue with a mutex or similar.

Comment: You're not checking whether the queue is empty before calling `rawImageQueue.front()`. And all accesses to queue from either thread must be protected by a mutex.

Comment: read about "producer consumer pattern" (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem), the first thing to think about after fixing your current problem - what happens when your producer produces faster than consumer consumes

Comment: @NeilButterworth New to mutex, should I enclose `rawImageQueue.push(std::move(rawImage));` between `m.lock` and `m.unlock`?

Comment: No. You should be using RAI, with either [std::unique_lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) or [std::lock_guard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a generalized example of producer/consumer on a shared queue. The idea is that if you're writing and reading from a data structure, you need some kind of protection around accesses.

For this, the below example uses condition variables and a mutex.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using std::vector;
using std::thread;
using std::unique_lock;
using std::mutex;
using std::condition_variable;
using std::queue;

class WorkQueue
{
  condition_variable work_available;
  mutex work_mutex;
  queue<int> work;

public:
  void push_work(int item)
  {
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(work_mutex);

    bool was_empty = work.empty();
    work.push(item);

    lock.unlock();

    if (was_empty)
    {
      work_available.notify_one();
    }    
  }

  int wait_and_pop()
  {
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(work_mutex);
    while (work.empty())
    {
      work_available.wait(lock);
    }

    int tmp = work.front();
    work.pop();
    return tmp;
  }
};

int main() {
  WorkQueue work_queue;

  auto producer = [&]() {
    while (true) {
      work_queue.push_work(10);
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(2ms);
    }
  };

  vector<thread> producers;
  producers.push_back(std::thread(producer));
  producers.push_back(std::thread(producer));
  producers.push_back(std::thread(producer));
  producers.push_back(std::thread(producer));

  std::thread consumer([&]() {        
    while (true)
    {
      int work_to_do = work_queue.wait_and_pop();
      std::cout << "Got some work: " << work_to_do << std::endl;
    }
  });

  std::for_each(producers.begin(), producers.end(), [](thread &p) {
    p.join();
  });    

  consumer.join();  
}
```

Comment: this should solve OP's particular problem with empty queue. though worth to mention that your queue has unlimited size, if work is produced faster than consumed it will run out of memory.

Comment: @Gruffalo Thats a good point. In the simplest implementation where you control the source, you could add a queue size to the container class, and have push block the producer. Although, I think handling backpressure depends a bit on implementation details. If the source of data is outside your particular program (e.g. any kind of distributed system), you need to have a backoff protocol, like a tcp window.

Comment: You might lose the `notify_one` trigger for `wait_and_pop` since you are sending it after the `unlock`

Comment: @curiousguy12 pretty sure thats not true. you are always guaranteed to have one work item available, as wait_and_pop is not greedy (you don't pop all work off, just one item). notify_one and wait_and_pop returns are 1:1.

Comment: also if you have the lock, that causes a spurious wakeup to the consumer

Comment: in wait_and_pop() if the queue is not empty it pops without a proper lock

Comment: When calling .join() won't that mean that it will be waiting for ever since consumer and producer threads are in infinite loop? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @BigCheese it does wait forever. in this trivial example its a work loop that isn't meant to end. the producer produces forever, the consumer consumes the work as its produced. very common pattern, for instance, in a server thats meant to receive messages indefinitely until its shut down.

Answer (score 2):

Your case is relatively simple as seems you have just one producer and one consumer. Also image processing sounds quite slow (slow enough to not worry about threads contention) and you're switching from single-threaded version so probably no need to bother with highly efficient lock-free implementations.

I'd recommend to study this pseudo code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem#Using_monitors, then to learn about condition variables if you need: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable.

Comment: The links are surely helpful, although I need some more time with my code to actually get it to work. I've also just found out that `rawImageQueue` is always empty.

Comment: I hope you prefer to do it well and to avoid re-inventing things as multithreading can be tricky

Comment: That's the intention. I don't think I'm re-inventing in any part of my code. I still don't understand why `rawImageQueue` is empty.

Comment: you start thread to execute `AcquireImages` that fills the queue, and immediately after that you try to pop item out of the queue. As acquiring and consuming is done in parallel and are not synchronised you have a race condition. More specifically staring a thread takes some time and so you try to pop item from the queue before it was put there

Comment: Your code shows that you lack basic knowledge about multithreading, it's why instead of addressing your particular issue (because it's obviously not the last one) I recommended to start by studying the basics. This can save you lots of time.

Comment: I understand this now, also the benefit of your answer is more apparent now that I realize there's a lot of more I need to learn about multi-threading.